# Should a header file be inserted twice?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have the following question about including header files. I'm learning about classes and the following question arose:

I was told that the declartion of a class should go into a separate header file, e.g.

```
//TestClass.hpp

#include <string>

class TestClass{
private:
  void init(); 
public:
  double r;
  double a;
  std::string Type;
  TestClass(const std::string& stringType);
};
```

in the respective TestClass.cpp I defined everything correctly:

```
// TestClass.cpp
//

#include "TestClass.hpp" 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void TestClass::init()
{ // Initialise all default values
  // Default values
  r = 0.08;
  a = 0.30;
  Type = "Hello";
}

TestClass::TestClass(const std::string& stringType)
{ // Create option type
  init();
  Type = stringType;
  if (Type == "hello")
    Type = "Hello";
}
```

If I include the directive `<string>` in the header file, do I have to include it again in the TestClass.cpp file?

Answer (score 4):

No, everything you declare in the header file will be pulled into any file that includes the header. You should add an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) / `#pragma once` by the way.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't, but I would do that anyway to make the code more clear: you're explicitly saying then "this code *requires* `string` to work properly". If, in the future, you'll decide not to use `TestClass.hpp` for some reason, the code would stop compiling and you'll have to manually resolve lacking includes.

Remember, that `#include` does no magic, it simply opens the file you specify and replaces the `#include` with contents of that file. So you required the file `TestClass.hpp` to be pasted into `TestClass.cpp`, but then you required the file `string` to be pasted into `TestClass.hpp`. In effect, `string` will be included in `TestClass.cpp` as well.

This arises the second problem: you have no include guards in your file. If you `#include` a file, wich also `#include`s your `TestClass.hpp`, you'll get compilation errors. The correctly implemented C++ headers looks more less like the following:

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_HPP
#define TESTCLASS_HPP

// Code

#endif
```

This ensures, that if your file gets included second time, it won't actually be used.

This can also be achieved by using automatic include guard:

```
#pragma once
```

However, this is non-standard, so some compilers may refuse to recognize it.